Affinization of a scheme is of finite type
Start from the total space $X$ of a vector bunbdle $E$ over a proper variety $B$, I tried to contract the $0$-section to a point. A natural way to do so is to consider the affinization morphism :  $X^a=Spec(H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$ comes with a natural map $X \rightarrow X^a $, as $B$ is proper, the only global sections are constants, so by the universal property, $ B \rightarrow X^a$ factors through the point $B^a = Spec(k)$. I have successfully contracted the base.
However, to be satisfied, I would like $X^a$ to be a variety, but I don't see why $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ should be of finite type as a ring.
I know from this post that the global section of a quasi-projective varieties are not always a finitely generated $k$-algebra, so I was wondering if you know any sufficient condition to ensure that, or at least one who apply to vector bundles.
I tried to see the global sections as the intersection of local ring in the field of functions, or via Cech cohomology, but it always boils down to the point that a subring of a finitely generated ring is not always finitely generated.

It's not finitely generated in general, see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4622809/question-about-a-variety-whose-ring-of-global-sections-is-not-finitely-generated/4622854#4622854
